# Emacs abbreviation with capitals

Tags: emacs, match, capitalization, abbreviation

Normally when I use abbreviations in Emacs the abbreviations are expanded such that depending on how you capitalize your abbreviation you get a different output (see table 3.7 in http://flylib.com/books/en/2.27.1.40/1/ for example). I use a huge number of abbreviations and this is rarely useful for me. I would much prefer to have Emacs not expand the abbreviation unless it perfectly matched the case for the way I wrote the abbreviation. For example if I wrote that "lc" -> lambchop, I want Emacs to not expand "lC" or "Lc" but just "lc".

I don't have very much experience using Lisp and I've spent hours and hours trying to change this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I assume you are using abbrev-mode and not dabbrev-mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docstring of `define-abbrev`:

> - `:case-fixed': non-nil means that abbreviations are looked up without case-folding, and the expansion is not capitalized/upcased.

To disable case folding, set `:case-fixed` to true on the abbrev tables you use:

```
(abbrev-table-put global-abbrev-table :case-fixed t)
```

Or, to do it for all abbrev tables:

```
(dolist (tbl abbrev-table-name-list)
  (abbrev-table-put tbl :case-fixed t))
```